# Google Gadget canvas view unable to talk to gadgets.views or .params until refresh?

Tags: javascript, opensocial, google-gadget

I've been working on a gadget that will run in iGoogle. In fact, it's finished, aside from a nasty bug that we're having a nightmare of a time hunting down.

*Note that the code snippets are in CoffeeScript; it's compiled to JS before we host it up for Google. We're also using Backbone.js for our code, but that shouldn't make much difference as all of our Backbone-specific code (`initialize` methods and so forth) work just fine; I've been able to isolate the problem parts of the code outside of our Backbone stuff*.

The gadget saves a list of preferred options to Google's `gadgets.prefs` object, as a pipe-delimited string (`55|34|101`).

```
prefs = new gadgets.Prefs()
prefs.set('paramname','55|34|101')
```

This save happens just fine, and any subsequent call to `get` that pref works just fine. They're even readable by a `prefs.get` call in the `home` view. It's when switching from the `home` view to the `canvas` view that the gadget isn't able to `get` those preferences (from the `canvas` view).

```
prefs = new gadgets.Prefs()
prefs.get('paramname')
```

*Only once you do a Refresh on the whole `canvas` view page will the gadget retrieve those preferred options.*

Now get this: we've tried passing these preferences as params between the `home` and the `canvas` view as well.

```
(home view)
params = 
    'paramname': '55|34|101'
gadgets.views.requestNavigateTo('canvas', params)

(canvas view)
@params = gadgets.views.getParams()
```

This successfully sends us to `canvas`, but after switching `home` to `canvas` and trying to talk to `gadgets.views.getParams()`, an empty object is returned. Only once a Refresh is done does the gadget process that same call, find the params, and use them.

In both views, the last piece of code run is…

```
gadgets.util.registerOnLoadHandler init
```

Which calls our `init()` function…

```
init = ->
    @params = gadgets.views.getParams()
```

…which returns an empty object, unless we refresh the page.

Any idea why this is happening? Am I not "kickstarting" the `gadgets.*` stuff properly? It's almost like I'm talking to a `gadgets.*` object that's not "bound" to my particular gadget, until I refresh the page (which then forces it to bind to the canvas view). Please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it seems, it's an issue with Google's new AJAX loading technology used in switching between `home`/`canvas` views. We contacted Google's iGoogle/OpenSocial team and that's the response we got. They were able to reproduce the bug with a gadget of their own. Until they fix it, accessing iGoogle with http://google.com/ig?aig=0 should band-aid the issue.